# Laravel blade condition in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have my data returning by ajax into table in blade but i need a filter in my returned data.

## Example

If I use blade loop I can use `@if ($loop->last)` in order to make special changes for my last record, but since my data is returning by ajax `(JSON)` I'm not sure how to do that.

## Code

> Commented the part i need filter

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'{{url('dashboard/getProjectReimburses')}}/'+projectID,
    success:function(data){
    $(data.data).each(function(_, i){
        var number = i['amount'];
        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            maximumFractionDigits:0, 
            minimumFractionDigits:0
        });
        var formattedNumber = nf.format(number);


        var row = `<tr data-id="${i.id}">'+
        '<td>${i.created_at}</td>'+
        '<td>${i.spent_date}</td>'+
        '<td>${i.cost_name}</td>'+
        '<td class="text-right">${nf.format(number)}</td>'+
        '<td>${i.description}</td>'+
        '<td>Attachments here</td>'+
        '<td>${i.statusName}</td>'+
        @role('employee|admin')
        '<td>${i.statusDate}</td>'+
        '<td>
// I need show this delete button only for latest row, for other rows just empty <td></td> //
        <Form method="DELETE" id="organizationFormDel">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button type="submit" data-id="${i.id}" class="btn btn-sm reimDelete btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
// I need show this delete button only for latest row, for other rows just empty <td></td> //
        </td>'+
        '</tr>`;
        @else
        '<td>status date here</td></tr>`;
        @endrole
        $('#visit_table2').append(row);
    });
}
});
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

Here is screenshot of my blade, I select 1 row from table 1, data shows in table 2

Now in table 2 as i marked it i want to show edit and delete button only for latest row other 3 rows empty `<td>`

[image: one]

Comment: Why don't you let that HTML part render on server & fetch that as string & directly display that in the DOM?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi sorry didn't get your point can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Your code looks horrible. Put your html inside view with some class or Id and update  content after ajax call.

Comment: @RishiRaut that exactly what i'm doing, i have table where it's body has id of `visit_table2` now the data that i get i loop by ajax and append it in that `tbody` `($('#visit_table2').append(row);)` which part of it is horrible?

Comment: @mafortis Create a method in your controller to receive your AJAX request. Get your data as per your logic & pass that into the view. After that instead of returning the view directly, you can use `render()` method to get the string representation f the view which you can return as reposne to your AJAX request.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi see, data for this table is returning based on id that i send to controller and answer of that id i sent is showing in this table that i shared the code, so basically what you said i have that already.  `e.g.` table 1 (data by php @foreach() )`  select 1 row and send id of it, table 2 show data based on id i sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Well I manage to do it the way I wanted, thanks to comments but my problem wasn't in controller unfortunately I couldn't convince friends that what i need is handle my ajax data on success and not controller.

Anyway here is my solution which works perfectly for me :

```
$(data.data).each(function(_, i){
  //.....
  var ms = _ == data.data.length -1; //get latest row
  if(ms == true){ // if is latest row
     // show my tr's with action buttons
     var row = `<tr data-id="${i.id}">'+
     //....
  } else {
     // show mt tr's without buttons
     var row = `<tr data-id="${i.id}">'+
     //....
  }
});
```

[image: two]

> Thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a partial view for ajax. For example when you will send an ajax request on the backend then you will use a partial blade file on the backend and there you can use if statement in blade file and you will return Html as response and then you will append that Html to DOM on success.

$html = view('partial-blade',['data'=> $data])->render();

return $html;

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a view and set all html code there. after calling Ajax and render view

```
$view = view('blade',["data"=>$data,])->render();
    return $view;
```

Comment: this is in ajax?

Comment: use in your controller. and return response to the ajax